# Most efficient way to Read from sql server table, modify and write to a different sql server table

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, database, linq

I have two tables where I need to extract data from one, do some modifications to that data and then write it to a different table.

I was wondering what is the most space/time efficient way to do this.

Is it better to read one record, modify and write the single record to the other table and loop this or is it better to read the whole thing, modify it and then write all of it into the other table.

I will be writing this using C# and Linq.

The tables have different column headings and structure.

Comment: the most efficent way is not to use C# at all. Do it all in SQL.

Comment: Or maybe even just having a view for it (depending on what the "modifications" are).

Comment: define efficient. explain the modifications. define other parameters (type of application, expected load patterns, the number and size of rows, which persistence framework you are using, etc.) There are probably 20 different ways to answer this, all correct in that they describe the "most efficient" way, depending on assumptions.

Comment: @Liam, I have to use C# because the manipulation in the middle requires it.

Comment: If you can do it using a SP, that would be the most efficient. By the way what sort of manipulation do you have to do?

Comment: If you really really want to use C#, it's probably going to be more efficient to read the entire dataset, manipulate it and write it back. But this all depends on what you intend to do in C#. TBH, this is too vague to really give a definite answer.

Comment: If you need to use C# for the calculations, why not put them as a CLR function in the SQL Server?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Indeed, the most performant way is to use a stored procedure or something (and then of course use batch/set operations).

If you have to choose C#, choose the option that has the fewest I/O-operations, since those are almost always the performance-breakers. That usually means: read everything in one go, modify, and then write it all in one go, but this is all very dependent on the amount of data you are modifying.

Answer (score 2):

Most efficient way would be to do this entirely in the backend. Write a stored procedure (most likely no loops will be required it should be a matter of INSERT/SELECT) and call that SP from your .NET code.

Answer (score 2):

The best way to do is the ETL process or script. 
if the modification require any end user UI activity before inserting into the table then the C#, using linq is good. if the Modification on each record is same then use the ETL or SQL Scripts to perform this.

### few guidlines.

For Data Fetching/INSERTING from One Table , Use Stored Procedure at SQL Side thats better.
using ADO.Net for fetching and inserting record is faster than LINQ.

***for same processing on multiple record
For bulk processing of record use table variables to fetch and interate on each record.

table variable is quite faster than temporary variables, it also helps in querying records.

Modify the operation or cursor or any logical based iteration on record or editing in columns data then 
insert it through bulk insert in the other table.

SQL Server is quite proficient on records processing in large scale. i would not suggest to get your same business logic into the C#,LINQ based app. try to process your business logic at sql server unless the end user needs to edit the record.

---

i have moved 1.8 millions records from tables  to a newly database structure tables, it happened accurately in 11 minutes but it took 27 minutes to (verification)queries to verify that everything is at right place.

might be it help you.

Answer (score 1):

A big question is your amount of data. A .Net client cannot "write the whole thing" in one request. Inserts and updates happen row-by-row. It certainly makes sense to read the data in one request (or in batches if it is too big to process everything in-memory).

But if you have 100,000s or millions of rows, this process will take many minutes regardless. I therefore would reevaluate your assertion that "the manipulation in the middle requires it [C#]". There are probably ways around this, for example by creating some sort of control table in your database beforehand that you can then use in a query or stored procedure to apply the modifications. The difference in performance makes it worth while to be creative in this situation.

Answer (score 0):

I have a complete working mini example here:

http://granadacoder.wordpress.com/2009/01/27/bulk-insert-example-using-an-idatareader-to-strong-dataset-to-sql-server-xml/

but the gist is this

1. Use an IDataReader to read data from the source database.
2. Perform some validations and calculations in the C# code.
3. The massaged data needs to be put into the destination database.
       The trouble here is that "row by row" kills performance, but if you do ~everything in one hit, it may be too much.
   So what I do is send down X number of rows (think 1,000 as a example).....via xml to a stored procedure.......and bulk insert X number of rows at a time.

You may have poison records (or that don't pass validation).  My model is "get as many that will work into the database, log and deal with the poison records later".
The code will log the xml that did not pass.

Not included in the demo, but an enchancement.
If the bulk insert (of 1,000) does not work, perhaps have a subroutine that passes them in one-by-one at that point........and log the handful that do not work.

The downloadable example is older, but has the skeleton.

Answer (score 0):

Well you can try to update column by column ,so that you don't have to loop for every row and your server trips can be reduced to the 2*number(One for fetching data one for inserting ) of columns you have .
You can get primary keys while fetching records use

> where in clause

and insert those values into another table.

But you have to elaborate more of your problem to get a satisfactory answer ,above approach will reduce  server trips and looping .
Or you can use SqlDatadapter.Insert

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldataadapter.insertcommand.aspx

------Hope it works.